# Draw a rectangle with the closest 4 points in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have these points (in pixels, 2x2):

```
positions = [[120 321]
 [341 318]
 [538 304]
 [106 107]
 [540 102]
 [318  94]]
```

Drawn in 2D they would look like this:
[image: 6 points]

I want to find smallest rectangles with 4 points, so I would like to have something like this:

[image: 2 rectangles]

What I tried was, in Python:

```
rotated_rect = cv2.minAreaRect(positions)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rotated_rect)
```

But it seems that `cv2.minAreaRect` is not able to separate in 2 squares like I would like to.

The positions vector is given in a random order, so I need to reorder first to get the rectangle, and these rectangles can be rotated.

Comment: I think you will have to pick one point and then measure the distance to all other points and pick the 3 other closest ones. Then from the remaining points, pick one and do the same with all the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this was what I did to compute it. In summary, I created a function to find if they are forming a rectangle or not:

```
def isRect(points):
    p1, p2, p3, p4 = points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3]
    cx = (p1[0] + p2[0] + p3[0] + p4[0]) / 4
    cy = (p1[1] + p2[1] + p3[1] + p4[1]) / 4

    d1 = int( math.sqrt( (cx-p1[0])**2 + (cy-p1[1])**2 ) )
    d2 = int( math.sqrt( (cx-p2[0])**2 + (cy-p2[1])**2 ) )
    d3 = int( math.sqrt( (cx-p3[0])**2 + (cy-p3[1])**2 ) )
    d4 = int( math.sqrt( (cx-p4[0])**2 + (cy-p4[1])**2 ) )

    if (d1 - 20 < d2 < d1 + 20 and
    d1 - 20 < d3 < d1 + 20 and
    d1 - 20 < d4 < d1 + 20):
        return True

    return False
```

To be precise, if the distance from every point to the center is similar (in my case, the threshold is 20), it must be a rectangle.

To find all possible case, I used the `itertools` library:

```
from itertools import combinations

for points in combinations(positions, 4):
    print( str(points) + " : " str(isRect(points)) )
```